# Concatenate fields from different relations

Tags: apache-pig

There are two relations

```
r1: {f1: chararray, f2: chararray}
r2: {f3: chararray, f4: chararray}
```

There is no unique key in either of the relations, but the number of tuples are the same.

Is there a way to concatenate the corresponding fields of the relations to get an output like f2, f4 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tuples are in the right order, you can use RANK.

```
r1a = RANK r1 BY * DENSE;
r2a = RANK r2 BY * DENSE;

r1r2 = JOIN r1a BY $0, r2a BY $0;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the join be by $0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use : CROSS (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#cross)

**Note** : Extract from Docs :  CROSS is an expensive operation and should be used sparingly.

**Pig Script :**

```
R1 = LOAD 'a.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray,f2:chararray);
R2 = LOAD 'b.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (f3:chararray,f4:chararray);

R3 = CROSS R1,R2;

R4 = FOREACH R3 GENERATE f2,f4;

DUMP R4;
```

**Inputs :**

**a.csv :**

```
f1_value,f2_value
```

**b.csv**

```
f3_Value,f4_value
```

**Output : DUMP R4 :**

```
(f2_value,f4_value)
```

Comment: Cross do not work because you do not want a full cross join, but only to join lines that have same line number.